# Uploaded post not showing on Facebook page wall

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to upload a post on a Facebook page wall using graph API (page_id/photos) and Objective-C in iOS, but after response when I see Facebook page my post will show in visitor post instead of Facebook page wall. I try to pass page access token ad parameter and give manage_pages, publish_pages and publish_action but still post is showing in visitor post. Please help me out.

Here is my code:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
    initWithGraphPath:@"/me/accounts" parameters:@{@"fields":@"id,name,access_token"}
    HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
         id result,
         NSError *error) {

            NSLog(@"%@",result);

            NSArray *data = [result valueForKey:@"data"];
            NSArray *fbPageAT = [data valueForKey:@"access_token"];


            NSURL *postImgURL = [NSURL URLWithString:upload_file];

            NSDictionary *params = @{
                       @"caption": _createPostTextField.text,
                       @"url": postImgURL,
                       @"access_token": [fbPageAT objectAtIndex:selectedIndex],
                    };

            FBSDKGraphRequest *r = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                          initWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/photos",fbPageIDToPost]
                                          parameters:params
                                          HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [r startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                                  id result,
                                                  NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"%@", result);
            }]; 
        }];
```